# Android self-signed client side CA certificate authentication fails

Tags: android, authentication, ssl, certificate, ca

Android self-signed client side CA certificate authentication fails, Can anyone share their experience dealing with similar issues? With the same credentials we are able to get it to work using CURL client.

We followed [this GIST](https://gist.github.com/milhomem/cd322bf3d0599ceb76fe) however we could not get through it.

Following it just led us to have this exception gets thrown:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:374)
```

Comment: Which android version are you using?

Comment: I am using API 23 level device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
// Input stream for self signed CA certificate
InputStream caIs = getInputStream(caCert);
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(caIs);
String alias = certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
Log.d(TAG, String.format("Alias: %s", alias));

// KeyStore for trusted CA certificate(s)
KeyStore trustedStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
trustedStore.load(null);
trustedStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, certificate);

// Create trust managers to be used for connecting to servics(s)
TrustManagerFactory tmf =  TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
tmf.init(trustedStore);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

// KeyStore for X.509 certificate/key
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
InputStream clientIs = getInputStream(clientKeyCert);
keyStore.load(clientIs, "password".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
kmf.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());

// Create key managers to be uses for connecting to service(s)
KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

// Create the SSL context
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

// Test by connecting ta server proteced by self signed certificate
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()).build();
Call call = client.newCall(new Request.Builder().url("https://testurl.com").build());
Response response = call.execute();
Log.d(TAG, response.message());
```